# "for loop" which loops once or twice only. Is if a better option?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

The value of count variable will be 0 or 1 or 2 only

The following is what I am trying to achieve
If count is 1, do something once, if its 2 do something twice

Is this a better solution

```
        for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
            System.out.println("PRINTING...");
        }
```

or this

```
        if(count==1){
            System.out.println("PRINTING...");
        }else if (count==2){
            System.out.println("PRINTING...");
            System.out.println("PRINTING...");
        }
```

I wanted to know which one is better and why.

Comment: The for loop is better. You might change requirement in the future and need to add a count of 3+. Don't want to have to copy paste `System.out...`s and add `else-if`s

Comment: Adhering to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), I would choose the first one.

Comment: By "better" do you actually mean "faster"?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the first.
Do not repeat yourself!
This loop unrolling seems to be a severe case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual requirements.

If "what to do" is always the same thing for each iteration, obviously the loop is better.

If it isn't, then it depends on the nature of the differences, the number of differences (e.g., is there a single special case, multiple special cases, can the special cases be calculated, etc.)

It also matters how extensible-without-changes you want the code to be.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the concern is performance, because from the point of view of code readability and maintainability the for-loop version obviously wins by an overwhelming margin.

If the code in the loop body takes as long as a println call, it does not matter.

If the loop body were really small and fast, then the main cost is going to be any wrongly predicted conditional branches or cache misses. If the hardware guesses wrong about the next instruction after loading a conditional branch into the pipeline, it has to flush the whole pipeline after the branch reaches the execute stage. That really costs.

The if version may result in a less common conditional branch pattern than the for-loop. Hardware branch prediction is likely to work better on common idioms that appeared often in the benchmarks that were used when it was being designed.

Cache misses can cause stalls while the processor gets the data to the execute logic. The if version is longer, because of having three copies of the loop body, so it has a higher risk of instruction cache misses. They use the same data, so they are equally likely to experience data cache misses.

My guess is that, if there is any measurable difference, the for-loop version is likely to be the faster. This is only a guess.

If the performance of your program really depends on how this loop is written you should benchmark it. Because of the dependence on subtleties of hardware branch prediction, I suggest benchmarking your program with each version on as many different processors as possible. If this is not critical enough to the performance of your program to justify that effort, stick with the for-loop.